# Atualizar todas as abas abertas no brownser de Uma Aplicação aspnet mcv c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-membership

Olá.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e queria que quando um usuário fizesse login ou logon atualizar todas as abas que a aplicação tem aberta no navegador.

Exemplo:

Usuário João esta logado na aba 1.
Usuário Maria duplica a aba e LogOff e na sequência faz login na aba 2.

Então eu queria de alguma forma atualizar essas duas abas ou fazer logout na aba 1.

Na minha aplicação isso causa problemas porque a tela fica com o campo login escrito João e na verdades os dados em sessão estão como Maria.

Já tentei comprar o SessionID de cada sessão mas a cada request é criado um novo SessionID.

O Gmail faz o que eu quero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tem como explicar o seu problema mais detalhadamente? Você pode melhorar sua pergunta clicando em [edit].

Comment: tentei melhorar hehe

Comment: Amigo, um dos caminhos que pensei aqui é voce fazer um update panel e ficar checando a cada x minutos se o usuário logado é o mesmo... caso contrario dar um refresh na pagina... mas é meio ruim essa ideia

Comment: Assim apagaria os dados da tela quando o usuário estivesse preenchendo.

Comment: O que você está usando para autenticação, Identity?

Comment: Olá, Estou sando o Membership.

Eu consegui resolver guardando o Login no HTML e depois comparando com o usuario que esta Logado atualmente, mas creio que não seja a melhor forma.